# WebAPI RouteAttribute not taking parameters from request

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a simple API-Controller and a `GET`action defined as following:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("My/{id1}/{id2}")]
    public object Get(Guid id1, Guid id2)
    {
        return new object();
    }
}
```

Calling this with

```
http://localhost/api/My/dd0d728-ae3d-4129-8a81-b0cdbcfd17c1/11063362-243b-4ff6-b3b6-85a9d611d347'
```

throws the following error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id1' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid`.

It seems like it has found the correct route but is unable to get the parameters set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the route you provided and was able to recreate the issue you got. But when I generated two new Guids and tried the route again it worked.

I think the values you provided can't convert to proper Guids.

Check to make sure the values can be converted to the intended type.

Hope that helps

Comment: This ends up in an `404`

Comment: Oh sh**!!! Indeed, in the first part there are only 7 characters instead of 8! Seems like `copy & paste` was not my friend today.
Thanks man!

Comment: @KingKerosin, No problem. Happens to the best of us. lol. Glad to help.